# How can you extract a scalar in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I'm using a for loop to slice a dataframe and then extract information from each slice. I then store that information in a dict so I can append it to a list for later use. My problem is that the infomation is not useable: it exists as a pandas Series rather than as the actual scalar value of the cell I'm trying to extract. Below is an example of the process I'm trying to execute:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.arange(0,15),'c2': np.arange(0,15), 'c3': ['A']*5+['B']*5+['C']*5})
iterable = ['A', 'B', 'C']
dict_list = []
for i in iterable:
    out_dict = dict()
    data = df[df.c3==i]
    out = data.c1[-1:].iloc[0]
    out_dict['out'] = out
    dict_list.append(out_dict)
out_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict_list)
```

Bizzarrely, the code above works, but when I change the dataframe to my real data, I get an `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` error at line 7, which I believe means that there is no index. In both my data and the example above, the type of `data.c1[-1:]` is pandas.core.series.Series and they both have length 1.
Even stranger is that If I run `out = data.c1[-1:]` inside the for loop, and then run `out.iloc[0]` outside the for loop I don't get an error.

Does anyone know why iloc would fail in this case? Is there a way to force `out` to be indexable?

Comment: after `data = df[df.c3==i]` - introduce the check of the amount of data in the slice, for example `if data.shape[0] !=0:`

Comment: Thanks @NoobVB. The always contains data, but the reminder to check the shape helped me find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you index a row/column with a number that is larger than the dimensions of your dataframe.

```
dataframe1.fillna("nan") # or whatever you want as a fill value
dataframe2.fillna("nan")
```

for example
`df.iloc[:, 10]` would refer to the eleventh column.

Comment: Thank you @Ipythonate, but in this case I'm indexing row 0 of the dataframe, which would mean that `out` has less than 1 rows. The dataframe columns in question also don't contain any NaN values, so I don't know what fillna() would do in this case.

Comment: give a try by adding couple of rows and then see the output

Answer (score 0):

Okay I don't have an answer to the original question, but replacing the .iloc[0] with .squeeze() solved my issue, like so: `out = data.c1[-1:].squeeze()`